# django.contrib.postgres.fields with SQLite

Tags: django-models, django-postgresql

In Django 1.8, what happens if I try to run unit tests against a SQLite DB when the model has fields from `django.contrib.postgres.fields`?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work! The import you mention requires psycopg2 driver.

Comment: While true that the import requires the `psycopg2` driver, that driver can still be installed even when using the sqlite db.